# Setting up a multi-value field with a fixed value (not unlimited) but with add another items button

Tags: entities

I want to set the number of values for a field to 3 but with **add another item** button next to first field. This button should disappear if number of items is equal to 3.

Comment: You want this functionality in your custom code ? Other wise drupal has the default functionality to control this.

Comment: Go to field setting page for example (Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » Article » Manage fields).In the settings page there is a option for field values in a select box.

Comment: Drupal render all fields simultaneously, I need this limitation with add another items.

Comment: It sounds pretty clear what he wants. The "add another item" behavior that is present when you chose "unlimited", but for a fixed maximum amount of field values and of course limited to that amount.

Comment: I think what you're asking for is: display a field with an [add] button next to it. When that button is pressed, show another field with another [add] button. If that second button is pressed, the third field appears, but no [add] button. If that's the case, look at form #states -- http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/using-the-drupal-7-form-api-states-system-to-create-conditions-between-form-elements/2014-01-20

Comment: This really shouldn't have been closed as unclear.  It is, as berliner says, perfectly clear, and an answer would have been very helpful.